# How to obtain the standard Laplacian as a particular case of the Fractional Laplacian?

Tags: laplacian, fractional-calculus

The definition of Fractional Laplacian is

[image]

I am trying to understand how to obtain the classical case as a particular case. If $s=1$, there is a pole in the Gamma function. How can I prove the particular case?

Thank you.